# how to save rand numbers in different txt files with php

Tags: php

i just need some help with script right here - i want to save every 100 rand number in different text files under a directory - so every time i make for loop to generate rand numbers every 100 random numbers i want to save them in different text file so how this is working but i don't know how to save each 100 rand number in a different text file that it dose not exists

```
<?php  

    function randz()
    {
        $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "testing/files/";
        $content = NULL;
        $start = 1111111;
        $ofset = 9999999;
        $counter = 1;

        for($i=1; $i <= 500; $i++)
        {
            if( $i == 100 )
             {
                $rand = mt_rand($start, $ofset) * 999999;
                $cut  = substr($rand, 0,7);
                $content .= $i .'-'. $cut."\r\n";
                $file_path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "testing/files/"."text_".$counter++."_".$counter++.".txt";
                continue;
             }
        }

        $fp = fopen( $file_path , "wb" );
        fwrite($fp,$content);
        fclose($fp);

    }

    randz();

?>
```

Comment: But why would you need that? :D

Comment: honstly , a friend of mine - asking to do this job. i have asked him the same question you have asked me - but he did't give me no answer because of his brother asked him to do this job... we have asked his brother - what is the purpose of this script he said his manger asked him to do this script. lol lol lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will first comment a bit on your code, if I may:

```
<?php  

    function randz()
    {
        $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "testing/files/";
        $content = NULL; // You are appending strings, 
                         // so in order to avoid a type cast, you'd prefer:
        $content = "";
        $start = 1111111;
        $ofset = 9999999;
        $counter = 1;

        for($i=1; $i <= 500; $i++)
        {
            // Why a loop and then an if with == ?
            // Maybe you wanted to use if( ($i % 100) == 0 ) ?
            if( $i == 100 )
             {
                $rand = mt_rand($start, $ofset) * 999999;
                $cut  = substr($rand, 0,7);
                $content .= $i .'-'. $cut."\r\n";
                $file_path =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "testing/files/"."text_".$counter++."_".$counter++.".txt";
                // Never pre/post increment twice the same
                // variable in the same line.
                // Does that increment counter in 1, or two?
                continue;
             }
        }

        $fp = fopen( $file_path , "wb" );
        fwrite($fp,$content);
        fclose($fp);

    }

    randz();

?>
```

Why not just,

```
<?php  

    function randz($file_number)
    {
        $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "testing/files/";
        $content = array();
        $start = 1111111;
        $ofset = 9999999;
        $counter = 1;

        for($i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            $rand = mt_rand($start, $ofset) * 999999;
            $cut = substr($rand, 0, 7);
            $content[] = $i . "-" . $cut;
        }

        $str_content = implode("\r\n", $content);
        file_put_contents($file_path ."text_" . $filenumber . ".txt", $str_content);
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < 500; $i++)
    {
        randz($i);
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I question a lot of your existing code. As such, I'm going to answer the question:

> how to save rand numbers in different txt files with php

Take a look at [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents).

A quick example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
   file_put_contents("{$i}.txt", rand());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function randz($fileCount){
  $file_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'testing/files/text_';
  $content ='';
  for($i=1,$l=$fileCount+1; $i<$l; $i++){
    for($n=1; $n<101; $n++){
      $rand = (string)(mt_rand(1111111, 9999999) * 999999);
      $cut = substr($rand, 0,7);
      $content .= $n.'-'.$cut."\r\n";
    }
    file_put_contents($file_path.$i.'.txt', $content);
  }
}
// create 10 files width 100 random content lines
randz(10);
```

Comment: let make it simple - i have count starts from 100 i want to save each 10 number in a a different txt file untill 100 finishes